# jQuery - Finding and validating a set of input boxes in a div

Tags: jquery, validation

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have a function that looks for all the input and select boxes in a specific div. It successfully finds the elements and will add an error label if the input is empty. But for some reason if I enter a value in the first input then it won't validate the other inputs individually. Ideally I want it to validate the inputs individually it seems like it's validating them as a group. Any ideas? I learn best by code samples, please include where applicable.

```
    function validateInput(event) {
       var $target = $(event.target);
       var validateInfo = $target.closest('#column').find('input, select');

       validateInfo.val() == '' ? validateInfo.prev('label').addClass('error') : validateInfo.prev('label').removeClass('error');
       return false;
    }

    return this.each(function() {

        var $headerForm = $(this);
        headerForm.on('click, '.header a', validateInput);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't validate the other inputs individually"? Your js is a little out of context, what is `this.each` returning? You assigned a group of elements to `validateInfo` but treat it as a single element: `validateInfo.val() == ''`

Comment: I have a set of inputs and when it runs through my function it adds an error label to all fields. But if I enter a value in one of the fields none of the other ones validate.

Comment: But `.find('input, select')` would return more than one element, so you'd need to iterate that list, but you're just calling `validateInfo.val()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have something like `.find('input, select')` it's going to match multiple elements, meaning you need to iterate them:

```
$('form').find('input, select').each(function(){
  if( $(this).val() === "" ){
    // add to error messages, set error classes, etc
  } 
});
```